# GETRAG G56 with Gen3 5.7L hemi

Tags: engine, manual-transmission, swap, compatibility

Your thoughts please.

I have a 2006 Ram 1500 with a 3.7L Magnum v6 engine and a GETRAG G56 6 speed manual transmission. I would like to swap the engine for the gen3 5.7L Mopar hemi, an engine offered for this vehicle but not with this transmission. Will this tranny mate with the hemi or will it require a tranny swap aswell?

Answer (score 3):

A couple of fundamental checks (without getting into the specifics of any engine or transmission combo):

- ***power suitability***

  Since you plan to install a bigger, more powerful engine you need to check if the existing transmission is able to handle the additional power. Any mechanical component will have some margin built into it but there are limits to what's doable.
- ***bellhousing bolt pattern compatibility***

  This is a physical fitment check to ensure the engine and transmission can be bolted together. Note that an engine and transmission combo with different bolt patterns can be made to work with an adapter plate, so you don't *have* to buy a compatible transmission.

Answer (score 0):

best way to find out is go to your local parts store or website type in the model make and engine and select trans as an item to purchase then go to a new window do the same with the new engine and see if the trans selection is the same. if it is great most likely it will work fine. The other option is call a dodge dealer and ask their shot techs to look it up sometimes parts stores will also look this up for you. You can also ask their parts department to look up which trans fit those engines.